# Private class property visible

Tags: java, class, visibility, private

How is it possible that `private itemset` property is visible in a copy constructor?

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Itemset {

    private List<Integer> itemset = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private static long count = 0;

    // copy constructor
    public Itemset(final Itemset other) {
        count++;
        this.itemset = other.itemset;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mildly interesting question badly asked.

Comment: Have you read the Java language specification section on access control (6.6)? It should make things very clear. The hostility in the last paragraph of your question is *not* welcome here.

Comment: Yeah, I went ahead and rolled that edit back, because it was entirely inappropriate. Let's be professional here.

Comment: Being confused is understandable and I'm pretty sure everyone here can relate to the frustration of something that you cannot comprehend at first sight, but I'm pretty sure your last edit will feed SO's hate machine instead of helping you.

Answer (score 6):

Because you are using a copy constructor ;)

More seriously: `private` variables have class level visibility; your `other` object is a different instance, but it is of the same *class*; it is therefore granted that instance members of this object will be visible from the constructor.

Note the "class level". It means instance variables from inner classes are visible by outer classes, and vice versa:

```
class A {
    private int a; // instances of B see this

    class B {
        private int b; // instances of A see this
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I'm talking about `other.itemset`, where `other` is foreign.

Comment: No it is not! `other` is an `ItemSet`!

Comment: This is weird! I supposed the incoming `Itemset` object `other` to be foreign for the present one!

Comment: It's a "foreign instance" but it's the same (not foreign) class

Comment: It is another _instance_, yes, but it is of the exact same class; and visibility rules apply: `private` members are class visible, for all instances of the same class

Answer (score 1):

The copy constructor is a member of the class, so why *shouldn't* the `itemset` variable be accessible from it? All variable members in a class are visible to the member functions.

---

To clear the confusion, yes, you can still access the private members across instances of said class because they only 'invisible' **outside** of said class' scope.

This is why it is perfectly valid to access the `itemset` member of the `other` instance from a call to the copy constructor for another instance.

Comment: No, I'm talking about `other.itemset`, where `other` is foreign.

Comment: Same reason. You're accessing it within the class, so you're granted access to the private members. The private members won't be visible outside of the class however.

Comment: It's the same class. Note that since you're within the scope of the class, all members become visible, even across instances of said class.

Answer (score 1):

- Being a class member, even `private`  is visible for the calss
- Every member of the class is visible in the same class
- Even inner classes can access the private members as they belong to the same class